# iOS 7 UITableViewCell issue

Tags: uitableview, ios7

I have an iOS 6 app that I am converting to iOS 7 using Xcode 5 in StoryBoard. Everything worked fine until I decided I wanted to add a custom UITableViewCell to a tableview controller after converting the app to iOS 7. I created the usual code to do this but when I run the app it gives an unexpected result whereby it just displays the contents of one cell row and it sort of floats above the tableview which shows what appears to be empty cell rows behind it. When I scroll the table rows, I see them scrolling in the background and the data being shown in the one view cell row changes while scrolling (see image attached). However, if I click on what looks like an empty row, it works correctly and it segues correctly to the detail view controller. I made the same changes to the app in iOS 6 using Xcode 4.6 on my other macbook and it works correctly (see image attached). So I'm thinking that iOS 7 handles the uitableviewcell class differently than in iOS 6 or I am making a mistake in the code in the iOS 7 app and not realizing it.

Here is the iOS 7 code that's not working correctly:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    ExhibitorsViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[ExhibitorsViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    if (tableView == self.myTableView){
    NSManagedObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.nameLabel.text = [object valueForKey:@"name"];
    NSString * booth = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Booth Number: %@", [object    valueForKey:@"boothLabel"]];
    cell.boothNumberLabel.text = booth;
    }
    else{
    NSManagedObject *object = [results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.nameLabel.text = [object valueForKey:@"name"];
    NSString * booth = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Booth Number: %@", [object  valueForKey:@"boothLabel"]];
    cell.boothNumberLabel.text = booth;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Here is the iOS 6 code that works (to me it seems to be the same, but I guess I need other eyes to view it):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";


    ExhibitorsViewCell *cell = [tableView    dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];


    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[ExhibitorsViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault   reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    if (tableView == self.myTableView){
    NSManagedObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.nameLabel.text = [object valueForKey:@"name"];
    NSString * booth = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Booth Number: %@", [object valueForKey:@"boothLabel"]];
    cell.boothNumberLabel.text = booth;
    }
    else{
    NSManagedObject *object = [results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.nameLabel.text = [object valueForKey:@"name"];
    NSString * booth = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Booth Number: %@", [object     valueForKey:@"boothLabel"]];
    cell.boothNumberLabel.text = booth;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

[Here](http://www.barrycjulien.com/images/iOS7-bad.jpg) is the screen shot of what's happening in the iOS 7 app.

[Here](http://www.barrycjulien.com/images/iOS7-good.jpg) is what it should look like (this is before I made the custom UITableViewCell changes).

Comment: So I recreated the view controller and custom view cell to see if starting from scratch will solve the issue. It doesn't. But it all seems to point to the xcode 5 storyboard and how it lays out the view in the custom uitableviewcell. It's doing some weird stuff. It's creating the cell and linking the cell properties linked to the uilabel iboutlets correctly but the viewcell layout is not containing the uilabels correctly. It's like there is another view on top of the tableview and it's putting the uilabels in that view, so they look like they're floating on top of the table viewed in the sim.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to drag the uilabel a little above the uitableviewcell until I see the cell boundaries highlighted. This placed the label above the cell. I then had to move the label back into the viewcell. Never had to do that in xcode 4.6. But, oh well.